# Android 2.2 Data Backup: How to backup DefaultSharedPreferences?

Tags: android, backup, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

I am implementing the new `BackupAgentHelper` from Android OS 2.2.

For it to work you need to supply the name of the `SharedPreferences` that you want to backup:

```
public class MyPrefsBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
// The name of the SharedPreferences file
static final String PREFS = "user_preferences";

// A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";

// Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent
void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
    addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
}
}
```

Problem is I use the `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` method in my application to get the default shared preferences instance. Now I need to supply the name of that file. How can I find out what name that is?

(And why do they not supply a helper that just does a `DefaultSharedPreferences` backup?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like it's called `"packagename_preferences"`

Comment: Yes, if you browse /data/data/<package>/shared_prefs you can see the files used for SharedPreferences. The name you need is indeed <packagename>_preferences. Also, I created an issue to ask for a more convenient way to do this for "default" SharedPreferences: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11922. (I agree with you, that should be there.)

Comment: How to backup data set with a PreferenceActivity?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at `prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` you can look at mBackupFile for the xml file name.